# Retrieving SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm working with an android application, and when my application is open I want to log in. I'm using shared preferences for saving data. 
How can I control three cases: if his credentials are null, if that user exists and does not have to register and save his credentials again and also if username and password he entered is correct and is the same with them he used when entered for the first time.

Comment: How can I retrieve data and make the control in three cases that i mentioned above?

Answer (score 1):

Use this code to retrieve values from sharedPreferences.

```
 SharedPreferences sharedPref ;
     sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
     int status=sharedPref.getInt("status",0);
     if(status==1){

          //do something here you want to do
     }else if(status==2){

        //do something here you want to do
     }
```

Read the documentation here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Also check this http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm